VBScript (vb.net) to save file as .xlsx not .xls
I have an ssis package that calls an ssrs report and it works fine with the exception of how it's saving the excel output.
simply changing the file extension to xlsx does not work, it corrupts the file. I've seen examples where people use ",51" at the end of the filename but I'm not sure where to apply that in my specific code. Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you so much in advance!
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()>
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)>
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum
    Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)
        Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
        Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
        Dim liCount As Integer = 1
        Try
            loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
            loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            loRequest.Timeout = 600000
            loRequest.Method = "GET"
            loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
            Do While liCount > 0
                liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
                loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
            Loop
            loFileStream.Flush()
            loFileStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim url, destination As String
        destination = Dts.Variables("Folder_Destination").Value.ToString + "\" + Dts.Variables("ReportName").Value.ToString + Dts.Variables("OutPutDate").Value.ToString + ".xlsx"
        url = Dts.Variables("ReportURL").Value.ToString + Dts.Variables("Location").Value.ToString + "&DateType=" + Dts.Variables("DateType").Value.ToString + Dts.Variables("ServiceArea").Value.ToString + "&StartDate=" + Dts.Variables("START_DATE").Value.ToString + "&EndDate=" + Dts.Variables("END_DATE").Value.ToString + "&rs:Format=EXCEL"
        SaveFile(url, destination)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
End Class



VBScript is its own language. VB.NET code is code, not script.

The issue is not saving the file. You're just writing binary data directly to a FileStream, which knows nothing about file formats. If you want an XLSX file then the data you retrieve needs to be in the XLSX format. You need to look at the Reporting Services URL that you're getting. That is what is sending you the data and it is currently sending it to you in XLS format. Assuming one exists, you need to use a URL that will send you data in XLSX format. This is purely an SSRS issue and nothing to do with saving files.

jmcilhinney - you are absolutely right! Thank you! The correct format was EXCELOPENXML - Thank you for steering me in the right direction!

The solution was found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver16
&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML
It turned out that it really had nothing to do with the VB but instead, the URL used to run the report and the output format available on the report server.

Describe the reason for the solution (as in @jmcilhinney's comment) and this will be a good self-answer to your question.
